# Creating a JavaScript Click Event to Queue Flash Animation

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

Greetings! I need to create a java/html button that, when pressed, queues my flash animation to begin. I believe I understand how it works on the AS3/ExternalInterface end, but I am unable to test it as I do not know how to properly code something to test it with on the Javascript end. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: What I am exactly looking for is literally a pre-made button code that, on click, calls to flash.

Answer (score 0):

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html#main_Defining_JavaScript_for_ExternalInterface_example

Answer (score 0):

call this function on your clicke event.
change ${application} to your swfs name.
btn_clicked is the callback function name inside your swf

```
function doCLick( ){
  var swf = "${application}";
  var container;
  if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") >= 0){
    container = document;
  }else{
    container = window;
  }
  var result = container[swf].btn_clicked();
}
```

ExternalInterface has issues with running as local content so you **may** have to upload it to your sever to test.